# Is 301 the correct redirect code for "fake" subdomains?

Tags: seo, subdomain, http-status-code-301

My site assigns each user a fake subdomain along the lines of

```
http://username.mysite.com/
```

which redirects to

```
http://mysite.com/shop/username
```

The second link is the one used internally, is assigned as link rel="canonical", and what I want to display in the browser as the correct url, the subdomain is basically just a convenience for my users.

The question is whether 301 is appropriate in this scenario? A 301 redirect is used for a link that now points elsewhere permenantly, which implies that the old link is deprecated. My concern is that I will attract bad SEO juju by using a 301 redirect whilst still advocating / promoting the use of the old link.

Comment: Do you want the user to see the username subdomain in the browser? If yes, you do not want to use a redirect as they will lose the subdomain in their browser. If you do not want the username subdomain pages in the search engine I would suggest you add a meta tag <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"> to pages served on the subdomain. This will prevent the search engine from indexing/following those pages.

Comment: Yes, I do want to see the redirected url in the address bar, which is why I'm redirecting in the first place. My question was whether a 301 (instead of a 302, etc) is appropriate, not how can I prevent a search engine finding the pages; "noindex,nofollow" isn't an option as the pages need to be visible.

Comment: Ah, then yes, you want a 301 redirect as philfreo suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 301 is the correct choice here as search engines will index the final URL rather than the subdomain.  I've never heard of any penalty for having too many 301 redirects. Other redirect types less accurately described what you're looking for (temporarily moved, etc.).

Comment: I'm not worried about the amount of 301s causing a penalty, but whether advocating / promoting a link that is 301'd will cause harm to my site's ranking over time, as promoting a link suggests it is an active resource.

Comment: It's one thing if you setup the subdomains for convenience to the users rather than typing in the full URL (Google does this with http://analytics.google.com ) for example, but I don't think you should be actively linking to the subdomain unless you switch your site over to making that the canonical URL.  That said, I still haven't heard of a penalty for doing so, but I could be wrong.  It seems like you could subtly promote the subdomain URLs to your users without actually linking to it everywhere.